# Using the View button on Notes tab returns blank form

Tags: contacts, bug-reporting, notes, civiprofile

I am using CiviCRM 5.68 on WordPress 6.4.2
On Civi contact profiles, when we navigate to the "Notes" tab and click the "View" button, we see a blank form to fill out, not the data we need to read.  I have checked other CiviCRM installs I manage and this issue appears on all of them.  Is this a bug that can be fixed in the next release?
See screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this has been reported at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4852. You can follow progress there.